# Writhing FIX tag containing multiple values into a dictionary using python

Tags: python, fix-protocol

i'm trying to export FIX messages from `.log` file to `.csv` file. i read the `.log` file line by line, write tags and values into a dictionary and then write the dictionary into a `.csv` file. the problem i have encountered is related to FIX tag `<128>` containing multiple values that i fail to read and append to a dictionary.

here is my code:

```
import os
import time
import csv

csvPath = 'C:/""/""/""/""/FixTakerLogs/'

    print('[START]:', 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv')
    fileLogon = open('C:/""/""/""/""/""/MsgMarketDataRequest.log','r')
    with open(csvPath + 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvLogon:
        dictLogon = {'8': '','9': '','35': '','49': '','56': '','34': '','52': '','128': '','262': '','263': '','264': '','265': '','267': '','269': '','146': '','55': '','167': '','63': '','12008': '','64': '','193': '','271': '','1201': '','1202': '','1300': '','10': ''}
        csvWriter = csv.DictWriter(csvLogon, dictLogon.keys())
        csvWriter.writeheader()
        for line in fileLogon:
            line = line.rstrip()
            line = line.split(',')
            X = len(line) - 1
            line = line[0:X]
            for tag in line:
                if tag in line:
                    tag = tag.split('=')
                    dictLogon[tag[0]] = tag[1]
            csvWriter.writerow(dictLogon)
    csvLogon.close()
    print('[END]:', 'MsgMarketDataRequest.csv')
```

here is the line i'm reading:

```
'8=FIX.X.X,9=192,35=V,34=XXXX,49=XXX.XXXX.1,56=XXXX.XXXX,52=XXXXXXXX-XX:XX:XX.XX,128=**AAAA**,**BBBB**,262=XXX/XXX-XXXXXXXXXX,263=X,265=X,1021=X,264=X,267=X,269=X,269=X,146=X,55=XXX/XXX,167=XXXXX,1300=X,63=X,10=X'
```

here is my trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/git/Py/exportFixMessagesToExcel.py", line 145, in <module>
    dictLogon[tag[0]] = tag[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I understand that i need to locate tag `<128>` split it and write both values into the dictionary before i go into the second `for` loop, what would be the best approach to handle this? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you change your original file .log to use ';' as the separator instead of ',' or change the ',' in "**AAAA**,**BBBB**" to other character like space.

If you don't want to do that, here is the way:

```
tag = tag.split('=')
if len(tag) > 1: #This means = exists
    key = tag[0]  # Store the key for later use
    ictLogon[key] = tag[1]
else:  # There is no =, so it should be part of the values for the former key
    dictLogon[key] += ' ' + tag[0] # Use space instead of ',' since ',' is used as the separator in dictionary
```

Comment: That will work, but i'm looking for a way to make this work without manipulating the source file .log file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

your following part of code read only a single letter in a line at one time.

```
for tag in line:
                if tag in line:
                    tag = tag.split('=')
                    dictLogon[tag[0]] = tag[1]
```

for example, when it will execute your described 'line' it will save tag='8'. So, it can't get splited it in two parts because there is no '=' sign. Therefore tag[1] is out of range.

## Possible solution

```
#arbitrary value of dictionary and then the line
dictLogon={'firstValue':'34'}
line='8sdf=FIX.X.X,9=192,35=V,34=XXXX,49=XXX.XXXX.1,56=XXXX.XXXX,52=XXXXXXXX-XX:XX:XX.XX,128=**AAAA**,**BBBB**,262=XXX/XXX-XXXXXXXXXX,263=X,265=X,1021=X,264=X,267=X,269=X,269=X,146=X,55=XXX/XXX,167=XXXXX,1300=X,63=X,10=X'

#splitting line for converting it in required list shape
line = line.split(',')

#removing the values without '=' sign
line=[ x for x in line if "=" in x ]
for i in range(len(line)):
    a = line[i].split('=')
    dictLogon[a[0]] = a[1]
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, i understand the issue. the question is how can i avoid this?

Comment: @Epsilon ..  There are a few entries in the 'line' you gave which don't have '=' sign, like '**BBBB**'. I hope it is ok if I remove them, or you can adjust them accordingly. You can check the possible soultion I added in the Answer and replace it with the respective part of your code.